# Performance problems with a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, performance, count

I am trying to retrieve the number of elements which are not null for a column. 
For example, if you have something like this:

[image]

and you want to retrieve the number of element which are not null for the column_name_1 you should retrieve 1. For the column_name_2 you should retrieve 2, and for the column_name_3 you should retrieve 0.

I am using this query in a MySQL database:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM
  my_table 
WHERE column_name_1 IS NOT NULL 
  AND [ others conditions ]
```

But, you have to run this query for each column, and for a lot elements (not all of them), I have some performance problems. Do you know how I can change this query in order to improve the performance?

Comment: Do you have the same indexes on the different columns? Is the performance issue always happening on the same columns?

Comment: The problem is that there is no index... The performance issue is happening for all the columns. I mean, it takes, more or less, the same amount of time, but I have to do a lot of queries so, I want to improve the time for all of them

Comment: Then start by putting indexes on them :-) Besides that, Raheel's answer could work, haven't tried that yet though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IF of mysql

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(col1 IS NULL,1,0)) as Col1,
    SUM(IF(col2 IS NULL,1,0)) as Col2,
    SUM(IF(col3 IS NULL,1,0)) as Col3
FROM my_table
WHERE [conditions]
```

This way you shift IS NULL condition from where to selection

Comment: I am sorry but it looks like the query has problems. When I run the query I get Error 1582, Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'IFNULL'. Then I changed the query to this

    SELECT
        SUM(IFNULL(col1,0)),
    FROM my_table
    WHERE [conditions]

But I get the sum of all the values, but I want to get the number of tuples which have not null that column, not the sum of all the values.

In the case I put in my question, I will retrieve 10 instead of 1.

Comment: @Manuelarte sorry about that i have edited. I conflicted IF with IFNULL

Comment: IF takes three parameters i think you should test again

Comment: Thank you @raheel_shan I tried with IF and it works, but I don't know whether this solution will improve the performance, will it?

Comment: well you can test at your end

Comment: it looks a little bit better